# Angular HttpClient Post with AuthGuard doesnt work

Tags: javascript, angular, post, httpclient

i have the following problem; The Observable always return undefined.
I think i dont really get how i need to use the HttpClient to work with AuthGuard.

```js
canActivate(
  next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable < boolean > {
  var bool
  var token = localStorage.getItem('Authorization');
  if (token != null) {
    this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/logstatus?token=' + token, this.authData).subscribe(res => {
      if (!JSON.stringify(res).includes('AuthorizationNotFound')) {
        bool = true
      } else {
        bool = false
      }
    })
  } else {
    bool = false
  }
  console.log(bool)
  return observableOf(bool)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.http.post` is an asynchronous action, so you are returning `of(bool)` before `bool` is defined by the result. To rephrase, `of(bool)` is being resolved before the POST even finishes and sets the value of `bool`.

Instead, you can `map` the response observable to a boolean and return it directly. Change your `if` block to:

```
if (token != null) {
  return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/logstatus?token=' + token, this.authData)
             .map(res => !JSON.stringify(res).includes('AuthorizationNotFound'));
}
```

This will make the POST observable map directly to the boolean you are looking for.

Unrelated, but if you haven't already you should consider adding error-handling logic to this call, because if the POST call fails your guard will break.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your fast reply! It worked with: if(token != null){
        return this.http.post('http://localhost:5000/v1/ts_p/logstatus?token=' + token, this.authData)
             .pipe(map(res => !JSON.stringify(res).includes('AuthorizationNotFound')));
        }